# Drupal 9 and CiviCRM 5.53, but jQuery is still 1.12.4

Tags: drupal, jquery

I am using Drupal 9 and have successfully updated to 5.53 per security advisory however libraries/civicrm/core/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js is still showing v1.12.4

Why is this, and how do I fix this?  Do I change composer? Must I replace jQuery version manually?

Comment: Do you mean jquery-ui? There is no 1.x higher than 1.12.4 for jquery itself.

Comment: Thanks - I guess I am confused. https://civicrm.org/advisory/civi-sa-2022-04-jquery-ui-v113 references JqueryUI where is it documented all the versions of Jquery? Here it says 3.6.1 https://jquery.com/download  Here is a security issue a scan picked up, bottom comment has resolution in jQuery 3.x but it looks like it won't be backported to jQuery 1.12.4 https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2432

Comment: jquery-ui update has been PR'd: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/24703. jquery itself might be more of a discussion piece. For the specific question about available versions: https://releases.jquery.com/jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your link to the PR. It mitigate the vulnerability